# Wix XmlConfig rename root element

Tags: xml, xpath, wix, wix3.5

Is it possible to rename a root element in an XML file using either XmlConfig or XmlFile? For example:

```
<config>
  <settings>
    <some setting="true" />
    ....
   </settings>
</config>
```

I want to rename "settings" while keeping everything in between the settings tags. So I'd like the result to be:

```
<config>
  <NEWsettings>
    <some setting="true" />
    ....
   </NEWsettings>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rename elements but you can copy all of them to a new node and delete the old node. Not ideal but you can let `XmlConfig` do the heavy lifting by adding temporary records to the table as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15787614/23852).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing a custom action.